# SQL SERVER PIVOT UN REGISTRO POR RFC

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

tengo una consulta donde traigo n cantidad de conceptos y necesito traer a los trabajadores con su rfc y conceptos en una linea por concepto.

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
SELECT rfc, [1005],[1004],[1010]
FROM v_campos_personalizados 
PIVOT
(
SUM(unidad)
FOR concepto in ([1005],[1004],[1010])
) as P
```

Lo que actualmente  obtengo es lo siguiente y lo que necesito es que si es el mismo trabajador obtener todo en una sola linea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intendado con un group by pero sin exito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La consulta debería ser tal que:

```
SELECT rfc, [1005],[1004],[1010]
    FROM ( Select rfc, concepto, unidad
               FROM v_campos_personalizados 
               where concepto in ('1005','1004','1010')
         ) As source
 PIVOT
  (
    SUM(unidad)
      FOR concepto in ([1005],[1004],[1010])
     ) as P
```

En la tabla derivada `Source`, te traes los datos en vertical.

Su salida hace el pivotado para la función de agrupación en base a los conceptos buscados.

Y esta se muestra en la primera `Select`.

[pivot simple](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/16/pivot-simple-como-hacer-y-entenderlo-paso-por-paso/)

Comment: Si tengo un catalogo de conceptos puedo hacer un select para mandarlos llamar y no poner el concepto fijo y si se llega a agregar un concepto se agregue dánicamente y no modificar la consulta?

Comment: Si pero eso requiere un pivot dinámico. Se monta de otra manera. El principio es el mismo, pero la forma es diferente. [pivot dinámico](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/14/pivot-dinamico-como-hacerlo-y-entenderlo/)

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa más versatil es usar agregados condicionales.

```
SELECT rfc, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN concepto = '1005' THEN unidad ELSE 0 END), 
        SUM( CASE WHEN concepto = '1004' THEN unidad ELSE 0 END), 
        SUM( CASE WHEN concepto = '1010' THEN unidad ELSE 0 END)
FROM v_campos_personalizados 
WHERE concepto in ('1005','1004','1010')
GROUP BY rfc;
```

Comment: También es buena solución, solo que tengo n cantidad de conceptos si se pudiera realizar una subconsulta para traer el catalogo de conceptos y no tener que hacer un case fijo y que sea dinámico

Comment: Hay una forma sencilla de hacerlo dinámico. Incluso es más sencillo que en PIVOT donde necesitas especificar los conceptos en 2 lugares distintos.